# Log outbound connections for SSL or TLS

Tags: ssl, iptables

Many vendors are switching off SSLv3 soon and I was looking for a way to log all outbound connections from a server to make sure they are using TLS instead of SSL.  Currently the vendors are supporting both, but I'd like to log if we are using TLS instead of SSL in case any code was missed.

Specifically looking at using iptables and putting in the syslog:  TLS connection made with IP information.  I don't need to decode the actual transmission, just verify its using TLS.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you look for the handshake and the version in the SSL Hello, you can detect it:
Using u32 module to look for a SSL client hello packet with SSLV3 signature:

```
 iptables -I OUTPUT 1 \
  -p tcp \! -f --dport 443 \
  -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m u32 --u32 \
  "0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 0 & 0xFFFFFF00=0x16030000 && \
   0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 2 & 0xFF=0x01 && \
   0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 7 & 0xFFFF=0x0300" \
  -j LOG --log-prefix "SSLv3 Client Hello detected: " # or -j DROP ...
```

From [HERE](https://blog.g3rt.nl/take-down-sslv3-using-iptables.html%20HERE), the first google return of "iptables ssl 3"

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do deep packet inspection. SSLv3 and TLS use the same port/protocol. The difference is primarily in the handshake.